# NumPy sum along disjoint indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I have an application where I need to sum across arbitrary groups of indices in a 3D NumPy array. The built-in NumPy array sum routine sums up all indices along one of the dimensions of an ndarray. Instead, I need to sum up ranges of indices along one of the dimensions in my array and return a new array.

For example, let's assume that I have an ndarray with shape `(70,25,3)`. I wish to sum up the first dimension along certain index ranges and return a new 3D array. Consider the sum from `0:25, 25:50` and `50:75` which would return an array of shape `(3,25,3)`.

Is there an easy way to do "disjoint sums" along one dimension of a NumPy array to produce this result?

Comment: Are those *ranges* of the same range?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `np.add.reduceat` as a general approach to this problem. This works even if the ranges are not all the same length.

To sum the slices `0:25`, `25:50` and `50:75` along axis 0, pass in  indices `[0, 25, 50]`:

```
np.add.reduceat(a, [0, 25, 50], axis=0)
```

This method can also be used to sum non-contiguous ranges. For instance, to sum the slices `0:25`, `37:47` and `51:75`, write:

```
np.add.reduceat(a, [0,25, 37,47, 51], axis=0)[::2]
```

An alternative approach to summing ranges of the *same* length is to reshape the array and then sum along an axis. The equivalent to the first example above would be:

```
a.reshape(3, a.shape[0]//3, a.shape[1], a.shape[2]).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: You don't need the repeated indices if the ranges are contiguous, i.e. `[0, 25, 50]` will do the same job in this case.

Comment: @Jaime: Oh! Thank you for the improvement - I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, it works exactly as I had hoped!

Answer (score 3):

Just sum each portion and use the results to create a new array.

```
import numpy as np
i1, i2 = (2,7)

a = np.ones((10,5,3))
b = np.sum(a[0:i1,...], 0)
c = np.sum(a[i1:i2,...], 0)
d = np.sum(a[i2:,...], 0)

g = np.array([b,c,d])

>>> g.shape
(3, 5, 3)
>>> g
array([[[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 5.,  5.,  5.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  5.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  5.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  5.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  5.]],

       [[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.]]])
>>>
```