# Efficient way of calculating sum of unequal sized chunks of tensor in Pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, sum, vectorization, pytorch

I am wondering if there is a way of calculating the following sum of unequal sized chunks of a tensor in pytorch

```
import torch
import numpy as np

x = torch.rand(1000,100)
y = np.unique(np.random.choice(1000,10)
```

here I have a tensor x of size (1000,10), I want to calculated the sum of chucks along the first axis. These chunks are split along the first axis and y indicate the end line of each chunk. They are in general of unequal size. For example, I can do this with the following for loop

```
cum_pos_lik = torch.FloatTensor(y.size, 100)
y = np.append(0, y)
for i in range(1, y.size):
    cum_pos_lik[i-1, :] = x[y[i-1]:y[i], :].sum(0)
```

But I need this to be faster for my application. Clearly the sum of each chunk can be parallelized. I am wondering if there is a simple way in pytorch of doing it. It would also be nice if a way of vectorizing it in numpy is provided.

Thank you!

Comment: Think you should be using `y = np.random.choice(1000,size=10, replace=0)` to ensure you have 10 elements in `y`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I used np.unique(). I was just making up a quick example to illustrate my problem. On the other hand I should allow chunk of zero length. In any case this is just a quick example.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798519/numpy-sum-along-disjoint-indices/32798907#32798907. This solution will work for you, with unequal chunk sizes, but a few quick tests suggest it won't give much of a speed improvement over the looped version. May depend on your exact use case, though.

Comment: @CiaoNeuner The slicing operation is already very efficient and then sum-reduction is fast enough. I would suggest keep this version.